# JavaFX TextField Validation

Tags: java, javafx

I want to validate whether the data input in the JavaFX TextField is integer or not. I want to do this validation only after the user completely writes the input and moves on to the next field.

Have tried an approach but it is not working, and I can't see why:

```
product_quantity.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
       if (!product_quantity.isFocused()) {
          if (!product_quantity.getText().matches("[0-9]*")) {
              total_cost.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
          } else {
              total_cost.setText(Float.toString(Float.parseFloat(newValue) * Float.parseFloat(unit_cost.getText())));
              total_cost.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
          }
       }
    }
});
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t just setting the TextField’s [TextFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textFormatterProperty)?  For instance: `textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter(new NumberStringConverter(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));`

Comment: If there is an invalid entry, I have to turn the total_cost fieldbox to color red. When the input is done correctly, I remove the color.

Comment: A small question, whenever I change the color to red, and then white, the fieldbox does not look like original as before. How can I take it back to original form. I use this: `total_cost.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");`

Comment: `total_cost.setStyle(null);` fixes the styling to go back to default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding a listener to `textProperty()`, you can add a listener to `focusProperty()`. This way the listener will be fired only when the TextField loses or receives focus.

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(!newValue) { // we only care about loosing focus
       // check condition and apply necessay style
    }
});
```